# passing multiple arguments in export module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to pass multiple argument in `modules.exports`. My code goes something like this:

Following file is a code snippet of index.js

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var number = 100;
require('./app/routes')(app, number); // pass our application into our routes
```

Following is a code snippet of routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, number){

app.get('/api/control', function(req,res){
  res.send("done");
});

app.post('/api/control', function(req,res){
  console.log(number);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("done");

});

}
```

The problem is when ever a POST request is made, `console.log(number);` prints `undefined` on terminal where as when I print when I replace `number` with `app` in `console.log()` it prints all the functions of `app`.

I also tried to switch the positions of `app` and `number` ,then it was throwing an error that `app` does not exists.

Comment: is `require('./app/routes')` really using your `app.js` ? Isn't it a different file ?

Comment: try this see what happems? `require('./app/routes')(app, 100);`

Comment: @pierre ,sorry that was a typing mistake

Comment: @ricky ,ya had tried it ,gives the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to pass the variable why not simply add it to the app object.

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
app.myNumber = 100;
require('./app/routes')(app); // pass our application into our routes
```

Then in the routes.js:

```
module.exports = function(app){

app.get('/api/control', function(req,res){
    res.send("done");
});

app.post('/api/control', function(req,res){
    console.log(app.myNumber);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("done");

});

}
```

Edited:

The following code will work to pass variables:

**app.js:**

```
var express        = require('express');
var app            = express();
var number = 100;
require('./app/routes')(app, number);
```

To pass the variable inside the function, you will have to bind it.

```
module.exports = function(app, number){

  app.get('/api/control', function(req,res){
    res.send("done");
  });

  app.post('/api/control', function(req,res){
      console.log(number);
      console.log(req.body);
      res.send("done");

  }.bind(number));

}
```

Comment: i did that temporarily ,but i was looking for a better solution as , i don't want to add anything to "app" object(preserve the original state of *app*),for code snippet i have used only the variable,but in my actual project i am using a large object.but still i will hit 1up as ur answer solves the problem :)

Comment: The reason you are getting undefined is because the second parameter of  app.get() is an anonymous function. It just doesn't know what the 'number' variable is. I've added the fix in my above answer.

Comment: amit thanks for the reply,but main problem is not app.get(),problem is module.exports,i am not able to pass multiple argumnets in there

Comment: That's strange. Its working for me with the above edited code.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do in that way ! Use the Router of expressJS and maybe the package Consign to pass multiple route file at once...

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


/* GET login page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login');
})
router.post('/', function (req, res, next){
    if (req.body.code === '***') {
        res.send({
            status: 'OK',
            token: ***
        });
    } else {
        res.send('KO');
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Then:

```js
const loginRoute = require('./routes/login');
app.use('/', loginRoute);
```

Comment: i am using angular on the browser side ,and it is handling all the routing,i am just serving index.html,i am using "app" in the http request,to call my api that is running on a  child process,so dont need of router in expresJS,my probelem is in module.exports and passing multiple arguments in it

Comment: Maybe have a FP approach for this, use a intermediate function who will take the parameter and return your function with your expressJS logic ?